# include option for get_posts works but is not limiting the number of posts

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am using the include option for get_posts and the numberposts is not limiting the amount of posts I have set right now which is 1, it simply loads all include ids that are set. Is it not possible to limit the number of include posts ids? Here is my code.

```
$image_list = get_posts(array(
            'numberposts' =>  1,
            'include'   => '559,117,129',
            'post_type' => 'ft_gallery',
 ));
```

Comment: Could you, please, run this code and copy result query here to make sure what you pass to function? `$getpost_attr['post_type'] = 'ft_gallery';
 $getpost_attr['include'] = $this->albums_gallery_list_of_ids($image_list_check);
 $getpost_attr['posts_per_page'] = esc_html( $post_count );
 $getpost_attr['orderby'] = esc_html( $orderby );
 $getpost_attr['order'] = esc_html( $order );
 $getpost_attr['paged'] = esc_html( $paged );

    print_r($getpost_attr);` Sorry for formating, commets don't allow me to breaklines.

Comment: I added the return array

Comment: just use wp_reset_postdata(); after the foreach

Comment: @MounerMostafa I don't see that making a difference. It seems like wp_reset_postdata(); is meant for WP_Query but I am using get_posts. If you could show a more detailed work around in an answer that would be awesome.

Comment: @amedv, sorry here is the return from your request Array
(
    [post_type] => ft_gallery
    [include] => 559,117,129,496,797
    [posts_per_page] => 3
    [orderby] => menu_order
    [order] => asc
    [paged] => 1
)

Comment: I edited the question to simply things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution is using post__in and making sure the list of numbers is in an array format. Thanks for everything efforts.

```
$image_list = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' =>  1,
        'post__in'   => array([0] => 559 [1] => 117 [2] => 129 [3] => 496 [4] => 797),
        'post_type' => 'ft_gallery',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'numberposts'=> 2 as described in the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/.   It's an 'alias' for posts_per_page.  Tested in shortcode on my localhost and it works

Comment: It works if you don't use the include option, but add a specified list of ids and it is not behaving as intended

Comment: What do you mean by ‘as intended’. I’d expect that it would return all the posts in the ‘include’ plus any sticky posts.

Comment: By intended I meant because I had the number of posts set to 1 yet all 5 ids were getting returned. All good though I just found the solution and posted and answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

> Note: The posts_per_page parameter does NOT work without setting the offset parameter.

Comment: I think the bigger issue I'm finding here is that it has something to do with using the include option, if I remove that then things work proper, but I only need specific post ids, not all the the posts in ft_gallery.

Comment: Filter them by category or tag. Put all posts that you want to loop trough in the same category, don't use specific id's of posts to filter them.